# I need some clarification concerning UML diagrams

Tags: java, uml

I'm making classes for shapes, just a quick question on the attributes of them.
The first shape is:

Triangle
 -sides:int = 3

When it says '-sides:int = 3' is it telling me there are three sides or is it saying each side has a value of 3?

The second shape is:

Rectangle
 -sides = 4;

Again is it 4 sides or each side is the value of 4?

Sorry this is a stupid question and as I think about it more it's probably the number of sides but if somebody could just clarify this for me it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: sides is an integer with value 3. Its not specified, but I suspect its the number of sides and not the side_length. Naming things clearly is important.

Comment: Interpretation of the meaning of a variable is up to the implementer. All UML is telling you is there is a variable with the name `sides` that is of type `int` and is initialized with the value of `3` or `4` or whatever. I think in this case it just means how many side a shape has

Answer (score 0):

Triangle and Rectangle (pentagon, hexagon etc.) are classes which implicitly define number of sides they have. It is not necessary to provide any attribute to define number of sides. If you define for example common class like "Graphical Object", this attribute is meaningfull and defines number of sides.

Answer (score 0):

Semantics of a model can only be intuitively deduced from its syntax (unless it is clearly explained). In this case "sides" aperently referes to number of straight sides of a shape.

It probably comes from an basic example of the inheritance, to show the concept. I would assume that there is an abstract "Shape" class, that defines this attribute, so it must be derived by all concrete Shapes. In order to fully define a shape, you should provide other attributes for new classes. Something like this:

[image]

Circle is added for more variety (sides = 0).